# Mathjax does not render colorbox correctly

Tags: latex, mathjax

I try to render `\colorbox{yellow}{\sigma}` and configurate the mathjax following http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html), but it just does not work.

Result: 
[image]

Configuration I find from http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html (I tried with and without autoload-all.js, both don't work):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the same issue [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33401/a-version-of-colorbox-that-works-inside-math-environments#33402) on https://tex.stackexchange.com/

> The problem here is that `\colorbox` reverts its argument back to text mode

Then you should write:
`\colorbox{yellow}{$\sigma$}`

Convenient sites to test your syntax: 
http://quicklatex.com/
(add `\usepackage{color}` in the Custom LaTeX Document Preamble option to test colors)
and 
[here](https://www.tuhh.de/MathJax/test/sample-dynamic.html) for Tex supported by mathjax.

**Note:** as `\colorbox` is displayed in red perhaps the command is not recognized, which means that your configuration contains errors. You can test with the macro [require](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#tex-and-latex-extensions) and write

`\require{color}\colorbox{yellow}{$\sigma$}`